# jQuery Cookie Plugin doesn't store cookie on rewritten .htaccess page

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, cookies

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^Uni/(.*)$ /Unime/profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /Unime/index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm using this cookie plugin:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

This is how I saved my cookie:

```
$.cookie('count', 1);
```

That cookie works on normal pages. But when I goto pages with 'Uni/' in it, it doesn't use the cookies that are used in normal pages. It creates a new cookie for the 'Uni/' pages, so what is the problem and how do I fix it?